# In Java - How to map resultSet into a complex object?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jdbc, mapping

How can I map a resultset from a few tables into a complex object?
let me elaborate:

Lets say I have these 2 classes:

```
public class User {
    private int user_id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    //getters setters...
}

public class Country{
    private String country;
    private ArrayList<User> users;
    }
```

The `sql` query:

SELECT * FROM users U, Country C WHERE c.user_id = U.id

gives me the following output -

```
id | fname | lname| country 
1  | Jack  | Levi |  USA
1  | Jack  | Levi |  UK
2  | Mike  | Brown|  Germany
```

How can I map these results into the Country class? 
I need make from it a `Json` string to get something like this:

```
{
id : 1,
fname: "jack",
lname" "levi",
countries : {"USA", "UK"}
}
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: From a JDBC ResultSet or from JSON String?

Answer (score 1):

Create a HashMap of  where user id is the key, and user is the value.  Then when you process the result set, do map.get(resultset.get(userid)), if it's null, create a new user, but if it isn't then do the logic to append a user to the country.

```
HashMap<Integer, User> users;
HashMap<String, Country> countries;
//inside the result set processing
User u = users.get(resultSet.get("id"));
    if(null != u) {
      //populate user here
    } else {
       Country c = countries.get(resultSet.get(country);
       c.users.add(u);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using jdbcTemplate of springframework, to implement the RowMapper interface is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
while(resultSet.next)
{
     users.add(new User(resultSet.getString("id"), resultSet.getString("fname"), resultSet.getString("lname"));
     //you can also add your countries to an array list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ORM libraries will do want you describe. Although most will likely perform 2 queries instead of a join. Usually you need to provide some kind of annotation on the list field so that it knows how to perform the query:

```
public class Country{
  private String country;

  @OneToMany(...)
  private ArrayList<User> users;
}
```

When you select a Country object the ORM selects all related User objects and adds them into the users ArrayList.

The library that I use is [sormula](http:////http://www.sormula.org/) (I am the author). See the [one to many example](http://www.sormula.org/onetomany/). No annotations are required if foreign key in User class is same name as primary key in Country class.

This page has good information about JPA OneToMany annotation: [en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)